# Why Can't Won't My WinForms Textbox bind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Basically, I want to bind a textbox in my xaml with a variable, DisplayNumFilter, in my c#. I would like to initialize my textbox to 20. I've been looking through several stack overflow posts and have tried many things, which is the constructor is kind of a mess (I tried many things and just sort of left them there). However, nothing's worked. My apologies with any mistakes in regards to formatting or terminology, I am still very new to this.

Here is a snippet of my xaml:

```
<TextBox Name = "NumAccounts"
         Text="{Binding Path = DisplayNumFilter, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Here is a snippet of my c# code:

```
private string _displayNumFilter;

public string DisplayNumFilter{
get => _displayNimFilter;
set{
_displayNumFilter = value;
OnPropertyChanged("DisplayNumFilter");
}
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName){
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public constructor(){ //it has a different name, I just use this as an example
   DisplayNumFilter = "20";
   InitializeComponent();
   Binding binding = new Binding();
   binding.Path = new PropertyPath("DisplayNumFilter");
   binding.Source = NumAccounts;
   BindingOperations.SetBinding(NumAccounts, TextBox.TextPoperty, binding);
   NumAccounts.Text = DisplayNumFilter;
}
```

Comment: You do not need to set binding in the constructor.  Have you set the DataContext for the window to itself so that you do not need to set the DataContext at each Control [e.g.  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAML markup `Text="{Binding Path=DisplayNumFilter}"` tries to bind to a `DisplayNumFilter` of the current `DataContext` of the `TextBox` control so you need to set the `DataContext` to an instance of the class where the `DisplayNumFilter` is defined.

This means that your constructor should look something like this:

```
public constructor() {
   DisplayNumFilter = "20";
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = this;
}
```

There is no reason to create a `Binding` object programmatically if you use setup the bindings in the XAML markup.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code, but I will focus on the main:

Your binding source is wrong. From that the binding source it will start with the property path. To resolve the property `DisplayNumFilter` the source has to be set to `this`.

```
public SomeWindow()
{ 
   DisplayNumFilter = "20";
   InitializeComponent();
   Binding binding = new Binding();
   binding.Path = new PropertyPath("DisplayNumFilter");

   binding.Source = this; // -> was before NumAccounts;

   BindingOperations.SetBinding(NumAccounts, TextBox.TextPoperty, binding);
   NumAccounts.Text = DisplayNumFilter;
}
```